# Python algorithm for probability that X >= Y where distributions for X and Y are based on 2 arrays of sampled points

Tags: python, numpy, probability, loss-function

I want to estimate the probability that a randomly drawn datapoint from array x will be greater than or equal to a randomly drawn point from array y. I want to do this by comparing all possible pairs of values.

I think that a naive implementation would look like this:

```
def probability_x_gte_y(array_x, array_y):
    gte_counter = 0
    n_comparisons = len(array_x) * len(array_y)
    for vx in array_x:
        for vy in array_y:
            if vx >= vy:
                gte_counter += 1
    return gte_counter / n_comparisons
```

But I believe that there is a more efficient way to calculate this, especially given that the distribution of the two sets of points in array_x and array_y are likely to be quite well separated (put another way the overlap between the two 1-D arrays is likely to be small relative to the total range of points covered.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much faster implementation is to **sort one of the array** so it is possible to find faster the number of values greater than a given one thanks to a **binary search**. This implementation runs in `O(n log n)` while the original runs in `O(n * n)`.

```py
def probability_x_gte_y_opt2(array_x, array_y):
    n_comparisons = len(array_x) * len(array_y)
    sorted_x = np.sort(array_x)
    gte_counter = n_comparisons - np.searchsorted(sorted_x, array_y).sum()
    return gte_counter / n_comparisons
```

On random arrays of size 5000, this is about **3890 times faster** on my machine (2.69s vs 0.69ms)!

Note that this is possible to write an algorithm running in `O(n)` time: you can use a *radix sort* on the two array followed by a kind of custom counting merge between the two sorted array. However, Numpy does not implement a radix sort yet and a fast counting merge cannot be easily implemented with Numpy.

Comment: Thanks - this is a great solution. I also realized that problem is equivalent to calculating the ROC AUC score - if you think of all of the samples in array_x belonging to the positive class and all samples in array_y belonging to the negative class. Nonetheless, the solution you provided is faster than using sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score

Comment: Nice solution! It might help to sort the shorter of the two arrays instead of sorting the first argument by default.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem I tested whether this makes a difference (sorting the shorter of the two arrays or the longer first)  and unfortunately the results are not straightforward - there is no simple rule that allows you to say sort the shorter or the longer of the two arrays first - it changes depending on the absolute length of the arrays. Sometimes it's faster to do the shorter first, sometimes the longer.

Answer (score 1):

If your arrays are small enough, you are correct that an exhaustive calculation would work. If your arrays are too big, then you could instead perform a simulation which would converge the correct probability, giving you an estimate.

If you can't exhaust and want a precise answer, then you need to break up the problem into smaller chunks. For example, suppose all points in X and Y are in the interval (0,1). If we break up that interval into ten sub-intervals, (0,0.1),...(0.9,1); then we could exhaust each sub-interval and work through the conditional probabilities. In theory, this could even be reduced down to intervals only containing single points, but I am assuming there will be a trade-off between exhaustion size and conditional probability tree size.